# Is the Sinovac COVID-19 vaccine accepted for traveling in Schengen?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, covid-19, vaccinations

I am traveling to Schengen countries] for Christmas and New Year, from Pakistan.

I am vaccinated with two doses of Sinovac. Is it accepted by Schengen countries, like Spain, Italy, Germany, France and Belgium?

Comment: Several of the countries you intend to visit have rising Covid cases and have/are considering re-imposing restrictions, largely targeted at the unvaccinated for now but that could change at any moment if the situation doesn’t improve. Unless you have a pressing need to visit, now is a bad time to be considering such a trip.

Comment: Very bad time indeed, Austria is already entering national lockdown and closing for tourists. Germany is quite strict against unvaccinated but if the situation does not get better, more restrictions might follow.

Comment: Yeah just weighing in here too, this is a very bad time to travel around various countries in Europe. If you can delay until sometime in spring it’s gonna be a much nicer experience.

Comment: The entry rules and requirements are very likely to change quickly in the coming days and weeks. Things which are acceptable now are very likely to be unacceptable very soon. **_No one knows in advance how the rules will change_**.

Answer (score 8):

Requirements vary depending on the country, how you are entering the country (air/land/sea), whether you hold an EU Digital COVID Certificate, which countries you have been physically present in during the past 14 days, and potentially other factors.

Sinovac is accepted by some countries (generally by virtue of it being on the WHO approved list), but not by others. In some countries not having an approved vaccine will mean you can not enter, whilst in others it simply means that you will require testing before (and/or after) arrival, and may require to quarantine.

The best source of information is the [Your Europe 'Travel and covid'](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/travel-and-covid/) website, which contains details for each country in the European Union. Using this website you will be able to confirm what is required for each country based on how you are entering the country, whether you have an EU Digital COVID Certificate or not, and which vaccines you have received.

Given you have not stated the order, timing or means of entry to each of the countries you've listed it's not possible to give an exact answer, but as an example for a few of the countries you've listed, based on the information on the Your Europe website, it is most likely that you would be allowed enter Spain, but would have to self-isolate for 5 days upon entry to Italy or Germany (if you are allowed enter at all - it's not possible to say without more detail).